# Separate an array in two arrays, the even and odd terms being separated in these two arrays

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I separate the odd terms in one array and the even terms in another array,i.e., go from

```
a={1,2,3,4}
```

to

`aeven={2,4}` and `aodd={1,3}`

I thought of:

```
a={1,2,3,4}

s={}

For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, 
 If[EvenQ[a[[i]]] == True, AppendTo[a[[i]], s]]]
```

but it does not work.

Thankyou

Comment: Have a look at `Cases` and `Select`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  GatherBy[a, OddQ]
  (* {{1, 3}, {2, 4}} *)
```

or

```
 Pick[a, # /@ a] & /@ {OddQ, EvenQ}
```

or

```
 Pick[a, OddQ /@ a, #] & /@ {True, False}
```

or

```
 Cases[a, _?#] & /@ {OddQ, EvenQ}
```

or

```
 Select[a, #] & /@ {OddQ, EvenQ}
```

or

```
 SplitBy[SortBy[a, EvenQ], EvenQ]
```

Answer (score 5):

kguler already showed the primary methods so here are some secondary ones.

One for fun:

```
a = Range@10;

Reap[Sow[#, #~Mod~2] & /@ a, {0, 1}][[2, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}}
> ```

And one for performance:

```
a = RandomInteger[1*^7, 1*^7];

With[{mask = BitAnd[a, 1]},
  {a[[ SparseArray[mask, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"] ]],
   a[[ SparseArray[mask]["AdjacencyLists"] ]]}
] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.234
> ```

kguler's fastest method for comparison:

```
GatherBy[a, OddQ] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.406
> ```

---

A fast method from [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo) for *Mathematica* versions 8+ (`Pick` was optimized after v7):

```
With[{mask = BitAnd[a, 1]}, Pick[a, mask, #] & /@ {0, 1}]
```

Comment: I'd stay with `With[{mask = BitAnd[a, 1]}, Pick[a, mask, #] & /@ {0, 1}]`

Comment: @Rojo That's significantly slower in version 7.  Is it better in v8/v9?  I recall Leonid saying that `Pick` had been optimized for packed arrays after v7.

Comment: GatherBy: 1.6s, yours: 0.73, with pick and BitAnd, 0.56. Both in v8 and v9

Comment: @Rojo Okay, thanks.  I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with one of the other options, but it can be done with [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html), as follows:

```
dat = Range[10];
{dat[[;; ;; 2]], dat[[2 ;; ;; 2]]}
(* {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}} *)
```