# Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list which is something like this:

```
{3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,42,43,44,45,46}
```

What I'd like to to is get the intervals which are in a "continuous" sequence, something like:

```
{{3,7},{10,12},{15,17},{19,24},{42,46}}
```

and get the extremes. Note that the original data (of which this is a small excerpt) shows no sign of regularity or repetition. Numbers start from 1 and get up to 200 (these numbers come from applying `Position[]` to an array).

Any pointers/ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7931716/618728

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `Split` in this simple case

```
list = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46};
{Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &]
```

What it does is that the last argument to split gives `True` only when neighboring elements have a difference of 1. If not, the list is split there. Then you can use the `Min`/`Max` approach to find the ends. `First` and `Last` will work too.

**Update:**

Since the attention to this question/answer is rather surprising, let me point out one important thing: It is the crucial difference between `Split` and `SplitBy`. Both functions take a second argument to supply a testing function to specify the point to split but the behavior is completely different. Btw, the same is true for `Gather` and `GatherBy`.

While the second argument to `Split` makes that it

> treats pairs of adjacent elements as identical whenever applying the function test to them yields True,

`SplitBy` does a completely different thing. It

> splits list a into sublists consisting of runs of successive elements that give the same value when f is applied.

If you weren't aware of this, a closer look is surely advisable.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know the Split[] function, now I know :)

Comment: @DavidCarraher Thanks. That many upvotes are rather surprising.

Comment: I very nearly posted the same answer (except using `[[All, {1,-1}]]`) first, but the phone rang. Next time I'll let it ring!

Comment: @SimonWoods It's a bit like digging for gold except the big rep pieces seem to be a mixture of *easy but not directly solvable questions* and *topics which are of interest by a lot of people*.. If you see such a question *swimming by*, let the phone ring ;-)

Answer (score 36):

**UPDATE**: After reading Ajasja's answer I realized that I was making this way more complicated than it needed to be.  My new code is easily an order of magnitude faster than my prior code or two orders faster than `Split`.

---

`Split` is a wonderfully clean method but it is not the fastest.  Without resorting to C code one can get more than **two orders** of magnitude improvement on long lists with this:

```
intervals[a_List] :=
 {a[[Prepend[# + 1, 1]]], a[[Append[#, -1]]]}\[Transpose] & @ 
  SparseArray[Differences @ a, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Compared to `Split`:

```
a = Delete[#, List /@ RandomSample[#, 15000]] & @ Range@1*^7;

(r1 = intervals[a]) // Timing // First

(r2 = {Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Split[a, #2 - #1 == 1 &]) // Timing // First

r1 === r2
```

> 0.0624
>
> 7.005
>
> True

---

A short description of how the method works:

`Differences` is used to find the steps between each element and the next for the entire list.

I have used SparseArray Properties many times on this site: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7815181/618728), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253138/618728), [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7445/121), [(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10653/121), [(5)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9797/121), [(6)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16461/121), [(7)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20175/121), [(8)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21220/121), [(9)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22058/121)
 Here it is used as a well-optimized method to find the positions of all non-background elements in the differences list.  I specify a background of `1` to find the positions of all other elements, representing a change of other than +1.  (In later versions `Pick` is also well-optimized so that becomes an option[<sup>(10)</sup>](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20175/121) but here we need to manipulate the position list itself so it may be the best method even in later versions.)

Padding (`Append`, `Prepend`) the position list with `1` and `-1` is used catch the first and last elements, respectively, of the original list.  Adding (not appending) one to the list is used to offset the positions to get the elements on both sides of each jump.  Finally, `Transpose` is used to pair off these values into the interval lists.

Comment: Spectacular, thanks!

Comment: @mag I was able to make my code much faster; please take a look.  And you're welcome.

Comment: Could you include just a short description of how the code works? What does the `"AdjacencyLists"` do? Why the `Append`/`Prepend`? Don't have MMA at hand right now...

Comment: @Ajasja I decided to add an explanation in the answer rather than comments.  Stay tuned...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard looking good! Wolfram should give you MMA 8 and 9 if he knows whats good for him. But where is the explanation of AdjacencyLists :P?

Comment: @Jacob I'll get v9 sometime soon, don't worry.  Please follow the nine links provided; if after you still have questions I'll be happy to answer them to the best of my ability.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't see it right away (its not in the docs), but I guess it somewhat speaks for itself :). I was expecting a SparseArray object, but I can handle lists :).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard your method appears to be a factor 5.815 slower than that of Ajasja, for your data. Comparing the timings in the different answers you might have computed 4.33845. +1!

Comment: Although not offering any particular performance benefits, it seems that `LaplacianFilter` can also be pressed into service for this approach. This might possibly be somewhat clearer since it is not necessary to prepend and append additional values to its result.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. Very nice trick with the `"AdjacencyLists"`. I hope you don't mind the edit (feel free to revert it).

Answer (score 22):

Recently, I had to solve exactly the same problem. But my data consisted of several hundred lists of $10^6$ elements. The profiler showed this was becoming a significant overhead for my applications, so I invested an hour into a faster implementation. Anyway, here is a bit more than another order of magnitude improvement over Mr. W's answer (and more than **300× faster** than the naive *Mathematica* implementation):

The algorithm is quite simple: Iterate through the list and every time a difference different from 1 appears `(curr - prev) != 1` push `prev` as the closing part of the interval and `curr` as the opening part of the next interval.

`` Internal`Bag `` is used for `O(1)` insertion.

```
compiledGetContigIntervals = 
  Compile[{{ind, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Block[{i, openInterval = 0, result = Internal`Bag[Most@{0}]}, 
    openInterval = ind[[1]];(* the first opening interval *)
    (* loop through all the indices and check for differences <> 1
       If that is the case stuff the interval *)

    Do[With[{curr = ind[[i]], prev = ind[[i - 1]]}, 
      If[(curr - prev) != 1, 
          Internal`StuffBag[result, openInterval];
          Internal`StuffBag[result, prev];
          openInterval = curr;]]
    , {i, 2, Length@ind}];

    Internal`StuffBag[result, openInterval];
    Internal`StuffBag[result, ind[[-1]]];
    (* return the intervals *)
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[result, All], 2]],

   "CompilationTarget" -> C, "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

(If you don't have a C compiler just leave out the options at the end of `Compile`)

And now the timings:

```
a = Delete[#, List /@ RandomSample[#, 500]] &@Range@1*^7;

    intervals[a_List] := {a[[Prepend[# + 1, 1]]], a[[Append[#, -1]]]}\[Transpose] &@
    SparseArray[Differences@a, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]

    (r1 = compiledGetContigIntervals[a]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
    (r2 = intervals[a]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
    (r3 = {Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Split[a, #2 - #1 == 1 &]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
    r1 === r3
    r2 === r3


(*0.040002*)
(*0.191011*)    
(*14.636837*)

(*True*) 
(*True*)
```

(If the code is not compiled to `C`, but to the `WVM` the timing is `0.74 s`)

Comment: Thanks to your answer I realized there was a much better approach to the problem than I had used.

Comment: When you have time, could you add the Timing for my new method to your answer?  I cannot test the fast C method in version 7 to compare.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Will do, but I'm afraid it will have to wait until Monday.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Updated the timings

Comment: Thanks for the timings, and the edit.

Answer (score 16):

A job for Mr Bray and Mr Curtis?

```
{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ 
 FindClusters[{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
   23, 24, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46}, 
  DistanceFunction -> BrayCurtisDistance]
```

> {{3, 7}, {10, 12}, {15, 17}, {19, 24}, {42, 46}}

Comment: While interesting this appears to be highly inefficient; I hung my machine attempting to use this on longer lists.

Comment: The recent answer by Fortsaint made me look at this again; unfortunately it *also* fails on e.g. `Join @@ Range[{1, 11, 18931, 18953}, {9, 48, 18948, 19000}]`

Answer (score 7):

I have made a solution using LibraryLink that appears to be even faster than Ajasja's function that uses `Compile`. Here is the C code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "WolframLibrary.h"

/* Return the version of Library Link */
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
}


DLLEXPORT int unitS_T_T(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    int err = 0;

    MTensor result;
    MTensor input;

    register mint *inputAndResultDataPtr;

    mint resDim[2];
    mint inputDataLen;

    _Bool isEven;

    input = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);

    inputAndResultDataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(input);

    inputDataLen = libData->MTensor_getFlattenedLength(input);

    //mAr stands for mallocArray, as this is not an array in the purest sense.

    const mint* mArHP = malloc(sizeof(mint)*2*inputDataLen);
    register mint* mArrayPtr = mArHP;

    register mint count = 0;

    isEven = (_Bool)((inputDataLen+1) % 2);

    //the n in nEvenIterations stands for "number of".
    //nEvenIterations tells us how often to repeat the code in the loop. 
    //To see that it is correct, consider how often you can increment 
    //inputAndResultDataPtr 
    //by 2, without making it point beyond the end of the integerData. 

    register mint nEvenIterations = (isEven? inputDataLen-2 : inputDataLen-1)/2;

    //we need count2 to decide how long the result tensor will be.
    register mint count2;

    register mint a = *inputAndResultDataPtr;
    //From here on, we consistently increment this pointer before assigning from 
    //its target value, rather than after.

    register mint b;

    *mArrayPtr = a;
    mArrayPtr++;

    count2 = 1;

    //We make sure that in the loop below, whenever we store an upper bound, we 
    //also can
    //store a lower bound. This is what safe in evenSafeLength refers to. 
    //The variable that the maximum between a or b, was set using an element
    //of the array beyond the (candidate for) the upper bound anyway. We do not 
    //need to store the lower bound
    //in a variable, as we store it in the array right away.

    while(count < nEvenIterations) 
    {
        inputAndResultDataPtr++;
        b = *inputAndResultDataPtr;

        if( b != a+1)
        {
            *mArrayPtr = a;
            mArrayPtr++;
            *mArrayPtr = b;
            mArrayPtr++;
            count2 += 2;
        }

        //if !isEven, the line of code below will make inputAndResultDataPtr 
            //eventually point to the last value.
        inputAndResultDataPtr++;
        a = *inputAndResultDataPtr;


        if( a != b+1)
        {

            *mArrayPtr = b;
            mArrayPtr++;
            *mArrayPtr = a;
            mArrayPtr++;
            count2 += 2;

        }

        count++;

    }

    //a and b alternating roles. We can predict which one is higher.

    if(isEven)
    {
        inputAndResultDataPtr++;
        b = *inputAndResultDataPtr;
        //inputAndResultDataPtr now points to the last value

        if( b != a+1)
        {

            *mArrayPtr = a;
            mArrayPtr++;
            *mArrayPtr = b;
            mArrayPtr++;
            count2 += 2;
        } 

        //count++;

    }

    *mArrayPtr = *inputAndResultDataPtr;
    count2++;


    //count2 should be even
    resDim[0] = count2/2;
    resDim[1] = 2;

    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 2, resDim, &result);

    inputAndResultDataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(result);

    count = 0;

    mArrayPtr = mArHP;

    while(count < count2)
    {
        *inputAndResultDataPtr = *mArrayPtr;
        mArrayPtr++;
        inputAndResultDataPtr++;
        count++;
    }

    free(mArHP);
    libData->MTensor_disown(input);

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, result);

    return err;
}
```

**About the code**

The idea is very similar to that of other answers.

There are some pretentious register keywords that don't change anything. I did a nice little trick with the variables a and b in the code to save on assignments. Also my intuition is that inlining the code twice in the loop only makes things faster (fewer tests `count < nEvenIterations`). It makes the code longer tough :-/. The code involves copying an array entry for entry. The problem is that the size of the result tensor is not known in advance and that you can only set the size of a tensor once.

**Making the *Mathematica* function**

To let *Mathematica* use the C code, we will make a string of the code and store it in the variable `cCodeString`. To do this, copy the code above, paste it between quotes `""` and click "Yes" in the dialog (to escape the characters).

```
cCodeString = (*Insert C code here*);
```

Now we process the code/string and make a function out of it.

```
<< CCompilerDriver`;
lib = CreateLibrary[cCodeString, "unitS"];
unitS = LibraryFunctionLoad["unitS", 
   "unitS_T_T", {{Integer, 1, "Shared"}},
   {Integer, 2}];
```

**Timing comparisons**

This uses definitions from other answers.

```
(r1=intervals[a])//Timing//First
(r2={Min[#],Max[#]}&/@Split[a,#2-#1==1&])//Timing//First
(r3=compiledGetContigIntervals[a])//Timing//First
(r4=unitS[a])//Timing//First
```

> ```
> 0.329104
> 10.1459
> 0.023
> 0.008142
> ```

```
r1 === r2 === r3 === r4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Notes**

I made the code with the scenario that there are many "jumps" in mind. When there are very few jumps, like in the case for which we compare timings, it is probably much faster to determine the positions of the gaps using a binary search.

For a constant number of jumps, I feel such a binary search would require only $O(log(n))$ time and that should be the main work in the algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

Not as neat as the other answers but yet another way :

```
alist = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46};

{alist[[#[[1]]]], alist[[#[[2]] - 1]]} & /@ Partition[Union[{1, Length[alist] + 1}, 
  1 + Position[Differences[alist], _?(# != 1 &)][[All, 1]]], 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{3, 7}, {10, 12}, {15, 17}, {19, 24}, {42, 46}}
> ```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer.  Revert if you dislike it.  Due to the compressed formatting of the original I overlooked certain positive attributes. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Many thanks, your edits are always useful.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not as neat as some of the others, but a pedagogical use of `Fold` that I thought was worth sharing:

```
sequenceBoundaries[x : {__Integer}] :=
 (Fold[ If[#2 - Last[Flatten[#1]] == 1, 
 {Sequence @@ Most[#1], Join[Last[#1], {#2}]}, 
 Join[#1, {{#2}}]] &, {{First@x}},  Rest@x] )[[All, {1, -1}]]

sequenceBoundaries[{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21,
 22, 23, 24, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46}]

(* {{3, 7}, {10, 12}, {15, 17}, {19, 24}, {42, 46}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how efficient this is on a large list but it seems ridiculously straightforward

```
MinMax /@ FindClusters@list
```

Comment: This is similar to cormullion's but simplified.  Are you sure this is robust without the express `DistanceFunction -> BrayCurtisDistance` he used?  If so this is a marvelously clean solution, performance aside.

Comment: I am afraid it is not robust.  Consider for example `list = Join @@ Range[{1, 11, 18931, 18953}, {9, 48, 18948, 19000}]`; your function returns `{{1, 48}, {18931, 19000}}` but these are *not* continuous.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks for pointing it out. Mr cormullion got the proper solution and I did not noticed it. Once corrected with the proper distance function, mine is just slightly more concise thanks to the MinMax function.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `SequencePositon` wasn't available back in `13..

```
{list[[#1]], list[[#2 + 1]]} & @@@ 
 SequencePosition[Differences@list, {1 ..}, Overlaps -> False]
```

> {{3, 7}, {10, 12}, {15, 17}, {19, 24}, {42, 46}}

if you make that a `{1 ...}` you pick up any isolated values too.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SequenceCases`:**

```
list = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
   42, 43, 44, 45, 46}

SequenceCases[list, x_ /; ContainsOnly[Differences@x, {1}]] // 
 Map[{First@#, Last@#} &]
```

---

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[list, 
 x_ /; ContainsOnly[Differences@x, {1}] :> {First@x, Last@x}]
```

> {{3, 7}, {10, 12}, {15, 17}, {19, 24}, {42, 46}}

Comment: Purely for pedagogical use as the `Sequence*` functions are slower compared to other list manipulation functions.