# Number by permutation

Tags: function-construction, permutation

I want a function that compute number of permutation in lexicographical order. E.g.

```
NumberByPermutation[{3,2,1}] = 6 
NumberByPermutation[{1,2,4,3}] = 2
NumberByPermutation[{1}] = 1
```

maybe something like that already realesed in Mathematica?

Comment: Do you mean `Position[Permutations[Sort@#], #]&`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just a note - any method generating the permutations and the searching will get *very* slow *very* quickly, and blow RAM soon after.

Something like this s/b *much* more efficient (e.g., on my goof-top, for permutations of length 10, it's ~30,000X faster :

```
pr[{}] = 1;
pr[{x_, y___}] := Tr[Clip[{y}, {x, x - 1}, {1, 0}] ] Length@{y}! + pr[{y}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
numByPerm = Position[Permutations[Range[Length@#]], #][[1,1]] &;
numByPerm /@ {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1}}
```

> { 6, 2, 1}

Answer (score 2):

The (now obsolete?) *[Combinatorica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/guide/CombinatoricaPackage.html)* package has [`RankPermutation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/RankPermutation.html),
which is very poorly documented.

It ranks permutations using a zero-indexing system.

```
rankPermutation /@ {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1}}
```

> {5,1,0}

The function seems to be based on the code given in *[Computational Discrete Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=AvUXQ98ynXUC)* by Sriram Pemmaraju and Steven Skiena, [p. 60](http://books.google.com/books?id=AvUXQ98ynXUC&pg=PA60).  Code for [`PermutationQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/PermutationQ.html) (also poorly documented) is given on [p. 55](http://books.google.com/books?id=AvUXQ98ynXUC&pg=PA55) of this ref.

I am reproducing the code below, and I hope I am not breaking any rules by  doing so.

In any case, it is [freely available on the web](http://books.google.com/books?id=AvUXQ98ynXUC).

```
PermutationQ[e_List] := Sort@e === Range@Length@e
rankPermutation[{1}] := 0
rankPermutation[{}] := 0
rankPermutation[p_?PermutationQ] := 
Block [{$RecursionLimit = Infinity},
(p[[1]] - 1) (Length[Rest[p]]! ) + 
rankPermutation[Map[(If [# > p[[1]], # - 1, #]) &, Rest[p]]]]
```

All works well with *Mathematica* 10, but the following inconsistency exists:

```
PermutationQ /@ Permutations[{2, 3, 4, 5}] // Union
```

> {False}

This can be 'fixed' by the following slight modification:

```
PermutationQAlt[e_List] := Sort[e - Min[e] + 1 ] === Range@Length@e
rankPermutationAlt[{1}] := 0
rankPermutationAlt[{}] := 0
rankPermutationAlt[q_?PermutationQAlt] := 
Block [{$RecursionLimit = Infinity, p = q - Min@q + 1}, 
((p[[1]] - 1) (Length[Rest[p]]! ) + rankPermutationAlt[
 Map[(If [# > p[[1]], # - 1, #]) &, Rest[p]]])]
```

Examples:

```
rankPermutationAlt /@ {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1}}
```

> {5, 1, 0}

```
rankPermutationAlt /@ Permutations[{2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
>   19, 20, 21, 22, 23}