# Subgrouping elements of list based on their values

Tags: list-manipulation

In a list of elements I want to group the elements which are in consecutive order. For eg.

```
list = {2,3,4,5,6,9,12,13,14,16,17}
result = {{2,3,4,5,6},{9},{12,13,14},{16,17}}
```

I have written the code below for it and it works fine. I wanted to know if I can use any in built Function to do it in a better way.

```
 For[
i = 1; res = {},
i <=   Length[list],
i++,
temp = {list[[i]]} ; While[If[i + 1 > Length[list], Break[]];list[[i + 1]] - list[[i]] == 1,AppendTo[temp, list[[i + 1]]]; i++]; AppendTo[res, temp]
];
```

Comment: closely related Q/As: [Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/125), [Ordered Subsequences of consecutive integers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140472/125), [How to detect if a sequence of integers is consecutive](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39211/125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Split](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Split.html)  is the built-in function you need:

```
Split[list, #2 == # + 1 &]
```

> {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {9}, {12, 13, 14}, {16, 17}}

Comment: Looks neat. Thanks.

Comment: @mrkbtr, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: kglr, I think this question reasonably *already has an answer* in [(23607)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121); do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the linked question(s)  asks more than what `Split` gives. One of the answers does use `Split` as a step, but imho it would be difficult for an average user to use that answer to identify an answer for the current question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is arguably answered in [Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121).

Nevertheless as it remains open it is beneficial to apply similar methods here.

Using `intervals` from my answer there this is solved with:

```
Range @@@ intervals[list]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {9}, {12, 13, 14}, {16, 17}}
> ```

This can be much faster than [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html):

```
intervals[a_List] :=
 {a[[Prepend[# + 1, 1]]], a[[Append[#, -1]]]}\[Transpose] & @ 
  SparseArray[Differences @ a, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]

a = Delete[#, List /@ RandomSample[#, 15000]] &@Range@1*^7;

(r1 = Range @@@ intervals[a])  // RepeatedTiming // First

(r2 = Split[a, #2 == # + 1 &]) // RepeatedTiming // First

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> 0.13
>
> 6.20
>
> True
> ```