# Split list of states by run lengths and discontinuous changes in state

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, performance-tuning, simulation

I was asked to look into writing some simulation code for a user, where the simulation output (`x`) would oscillate between three possible states:

```
states[x_, γ_] := Which[
x < -γ,  1 (*top*),
x < γ , -1 (*bottom*),
True  ,  0   (*middle*)]
```

The simulation essentially boiled down to the following, and what they were interested in is computing the lengths runs in each state - which could be easily computed with `SplitBy`:

```
γ = 0.9;
sampleSimulation = RandomChoice[{-1, 0, 1}, 1000000];
runLengths = Switch[Sign[#[[1]]], 
     1, {"top", Length[#]},
    -1, {"bottom", Length[#]}, 
     0, {"middle", Length[#]}
 ] & /@ SplitBy[sampleSimulation, states[#, γ] &]
```

However, if the simulation output moved between the `"top"` and `"bottom"` states (in either direction) without occupying the `"middle"` state they needed this information in `runLengths` via the string `"unoccupied middle"`.

The following code achieves that and is surprisingly performant and the experimenter was happy. However it feels unnecessary to `SplitBy` and then `Reap` and `Sow` with a `Do` loop to find where the simulation moves seemlessly between `"top"` and `"bottom"`. What would be a more natural, and less wasteful method to solve such a problem?

```
runLengthsFunc[list_, γ_] :=
 Block[{splitting},
  splitting = 
   Switch[Sign[#[[1]]], 
      1, {"top", Length[#]}, -1, {"bottom", Length[#]}, 
      0, {"middle", Length[#]}] & /@ 
    SplitBy[list, states[#, γ] &];
  Append[Flatten[
    Reap[Do[If[(splitting[[k, 1]] == "top" && 
           splitting[[k + 1, 1]] == "bottom") || (splitting[[k, 1]] ==
             "bottom" && splitting[[k + 1, 1]] == "top"), 
        Sow[{splitting[[k]], "unoccupied middle"}],
        Sow[{splitting[[k]]}]],
       {k, Length[splitting] - 1}
       ]][[2]], 2], splitting[[-1]]]]
```

Timing:

```
In[10]:=AbsoluteTiming[runLengthsFunc[sampleSimulation, γ];]
Out[10]:={7.526282, Null}
```

**Solution Choosing**

Thanks for the three very different solutions, as requested the focus was on different methodologies rather than sheer blistering speed.

I'm going to accept Mr Wizard's answer as it provided the most different approach (and best learning experience for me) as well as exceptional speed - under a second for an initial set of 1,000,000 states. However, there was an apparently superfluous process; `Unitize` where a list already contained only 0,1.

Kguler's method falls apart for more than ~3000 elements, but is a great example of pattern matching. And it's great to see in both this and Mr Wizard's solutions the convergent evolution of SE toward Composition.

Leonid's answer introduced me to linked lists which will be a useful tool for similar problems I have. Unfortunately, I can't benchmark Leonid's as he elected to focus on methodology rather than speed so did not include an implementation of `runLengths` - but the linking of lists is much more performant than my `Reap[Do[Sow]` approach.

Comment: `Position[Abs[Differences@sampleSimulation], 2]` will give you list of positions where next position is a jump up/down past 0. You can then use that to insert the unoccupied tag.

Comment: @rasher I'd like to still see where you were going, would you undelete and post as a comment?

Comment: Thanks for the Accept. :-)  Good catch on `Unitize`; at the moment I agree, it appears superfluous.

Comment: +1 on the question for adding the "Solution Choosing" section - wish more would explain their process in that way, or when changing accepts the why (without which I assume the answer(s) were non-responsive).

Comment: @rasher I'm in Saudi Arabia on consultancy where there is very little entertainment other than going through my list of "Things I forgot to reply to". The best questions I've read become discussions with the answerers, proof of a good community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I'm late to the party but here is my approach.  Common functions and data:

```
trinarize[a_List, γ_?NumericQ] := UnitStep[a - γ] + UnitStep[γ + a]
labels = {0 -> "bottom", 1 -> "middle", 2 -> "top"};

SeedRandom[1]
sampleSimulation = RandomChoice[{-1, 0, 1}, 20]
```

> ```
> {0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0}
> ```

#### Method #1

```
Split @ trinarize[sampleSimulation, 0.9]  (* 0.9 is γ *)

Split[%, Abs[#[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < 2 &]

Join @@ Riffle[%, {{"unoccupied middle"}}]

% /. p : {x_ ..} :> {x /. labels, Length@p}
```

> ```
> {{1}, {0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {2}, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}
>
> {{{1}, {0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{2}}, {{0}, {1}, {2}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 
>    1}}}
>
> {{1}, {0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, "unoccupied middle", {2},
>   "unoccupied middle", {0}, {1}, {2}, "unoccupied middle", {0, 0}, {1, 1}}
>
> {{"middle", 1}, {"bottom", 1}, {"middle", 2}, {"bottom", 3}, {"middle", 1}, {"bottom", 
>   4}, "unoccupied middle", {"top", 1}, "unoccupied middle", {"bottom", 1}, {"middle", 
>   1}, {"top", 1}, "unoccupied middle", {"bottom", 2}, {"middle", 2}}
> ```

#### Method #2

```
s1 = Split @ trinarize[sampleSimulation, 0.9]  (* 0.9 is γ *)
s2 = {First @ # /. labels, Length @ #} & /@ s1
n = Length @ s1;
jumps = SparseArray[Abs @ Differences @ s1[[All, 1]] - 1]["AdjacencyLists"]

Clip[Ordering @ Join[Range@n, jumps], {1, n}, {1, n + 1}];
Append[s2, "unoccupied middle"][[%]]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {2}, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}
>
> {{"middle", 1}, {"bottom", 1}, {"middle", 2}, {"bottom", 3}, {"middle", 1}, {"bottom", 
>   4}, {"top", 1}, {"bottom", 1}, {"middle", 1}, {"top", 1}, {"bottom", 2}, {"middle", 2}}
>
> {6, 7, 10}
>
> {{"middle", 1}, {"bottom", 1}, {"middle", 2}, {"bottom", 3}, {"middle", 1}, {"bottom", 
>   4}, "unoccupied middle", {"top", 1}, "unoccupied middle", {"bottom", 1}, {"middle", 
>   1}, {"top", 1}, "unoccupied middle", {"bottom", 2}, {"middle", 2}}
> ```

Comment: @rasher Thanks!  I see you deleted your answer.  I found another way to make the insertions that I like well enough (it's cleaner, but not as fast).  Why don't you resurrect your answer and I'll leave that ("method #2" to you?

Comment: Nah, I doofused the question by not paying attention, penance is deletion...

Comment: Need to understand the SparseArray SubValues better - it's part of your standard toolbox, where'd you gain the knowledge?

Comment: @Martin I first learned about `SparseArray` Properties from a post by Oliver Ruebenkoenig on MathGroup.  Since them I've made frequent use of them, e.g. as linked [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/121).  You can get a list of the Properties with `SparseArray[{1}]["Properties"]`.  Experimentation is perhaps the best way to understand them.  (continued)

Comment: @Martin `"NonzeroPositions"` is actually non-*background* positions (a `SparseArray` has a default background of zero but it can be set to other things), in multidimensional form; `"AdjacencyLists"` is the same but for each row and without the first dimension.  If you have any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I think your core idea about post-processing the splittings is a good one. It can be expressed somewhat more elegantly (although elegance is a subjective matter) with the help of linked lists rather than `Reap/Sow`:

```
ClearAll[ll];
SetAttributes[ll,HoldAllComplete];
toLinkedList[l_List]:=
    Fold[ll[#2,#1]&,ll[],Reverse[l]]
```

and

```
ClearAll[process];
process[runlengths_]:=
    Block[{$IterationLimit=\[Infinity]},
        process[ll[],toLinkedList[runlengths]]
    ];
process[accum_,ll[t:{"top",_},tail:ll[{"bottom",_},_]]]:=
    process[ll[ll[accum,t],"unoccupied middle"],tail];

process[accum_,ll[t:{"bottom",_},tail:ll[{"top",_},_]]]:=
    process[ll[ll[accum,t],"unoccupied middle"],tail];

process[accum_,ll[head_,tail_]]:=
    process[ll[accum,head],tail];

process[accum_,ll[]]:=
    List@@Flatten[accum,\[Infinity],ll];
```

On your test, this code seems to be slightly faster too, on my machine:

```
(runLengths = ... ); // AbsoluteTiming

(* {6.667189, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[runLengthsFunc[sampleSimulation, \[Gamma]];]

(* {9.505267, Null} *)

process[runLengths]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.383734, Null} *)
```

which means that this method is roughly twice faster than the one based on `Reap/Sow`. But my main point was not speed but a more clear and declarative way to express the algorithm.

Comment: Leonid, I hope to see you include your own code to generate `runLenghts`.  Then we can see what this code can really do. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard May be later :) You already squeezed nearly everything out of this one, it terms of speed. Besides, I wasn't really concerned with speed here.

Comment: While elegance is subjective, seeing Fold in an example I understand is wonderful - thanks. Need to explore the answers when not on mobile device before I can accept one.

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley Glad you liked it. `Fold` here serves a role of a helper function to construct the linked list. This is basically your own algorithm, just rewritten using linked lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1];
sampleSimulation = RandomChoice[{-1, 0, 1}, 20]

rplcR = {(0) -> "middle", {beg___, mid : Alternatives @@ 
   PatternSequence @@@ {{"top", "bottom"}, {"bottom", "top"}},  end___} :>
     {beg, Sequence @@ Riffle[{mid}, "jump"], end}};
jtsrcF = Composition[Join @@ # &, Tally /@ # &, Split, # //. rplcR &, 
                   Clip[#1, #2 {-1, 1}, {"bottom", "top"}] &];
jtsrcF[sampleSimulation, .5]
(* {0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0,  0} *)
(* {{"middle", 1}, {"bottom", 1}, {"middle", 2}, {"bottom", 3}, {"middle", 1},
    {"bottom", 4}, {"jump", 1}, {"top", 1}, {"jump", 1}, {"bottom", 1},
    {"middle", 1}, {"top", 1}, {"jump", 1}, {"bottom", 2}, {"middle", 2}} *)
```

Comment: +1 for PatternSequences and patterns in general. I can't benchmark this at the moment, if you don't update I'll put timings into the question.

Comment: @MartinJohnHadley, thanks for the vote. I don't think this stands a good chance in benchmarks:)