# Faster "stuttering" accumulate?

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

Given some list of arbitrary precision numbers, e.g. (actual lists are 1M+ elements long):

```
test={0, 2, 2, 47839283, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0}
```

I need to accumulate the list, but where a specified element value is treated as "clear", that is, the accumulation is reset to zero at that point in the list and continues.

With the above example, using zero as the "clear", the result would be e.g.:

```
{0, 2, 4, 47839287, 47839289, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0}
```

I'm using

```
Function[{lst, clr}, FoldList[If[#2 == clr, 0, +##] &, lst[[1]], Rest@lst]][test, 0]
```

Seems pretty snappy, wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: `FoldList` is what I have used before.  I doubt it can be beaten outside of a compiled solution, but as always I'd love to be proven wrong on such things.  By the way it truly pains my terse-obsessed mind every time I see `Fold[f, First[list], Rest[list]]` or the equivalent written out, as I have customized `Fold[f, list]` to perform the same.  Have you considered that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I figured it might be close to optimal, but I'm sure you too have had the "have I missed something obvious..." feeling. Might you illuminate your comment re: terseness?

Comment: Please see my `Fold` customization here: [(5433867)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5433867).  *Edit:* I just updated that post to match the current customization that I use.

Comment: For the sake of the experiment shall we consider the "clear" to occur frequently as shown, or rarely?

Comment: @mr: Frequency varies, from quite sparse (nearly non-existent) to fairly heavy (~25%), with no way ahead of time knowing sparsity.

Answer (score 12):

### Notes:

I completely overlooked the fact that rasher specified arbitrary precision input when crafting my functions.  Because of this the numeric methods I used will not be as fast.  However, to my surprise it seems that at least `fn2` is *still* faster than the `FoldList` method on arbitrary precision data.

Timings with resets on average at about 1 in 40:

```
big = RandomInteger[{-1*^20, 1*^20}, 1*^6];
big = Clip[big, {-∞, 0.95*^20}, {0, 0}];

fn1[big, 0] // timeAvg
fn2[big]    // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.858
>
> 0.499
> ```

Not quite the performance on packed arrays demonstrated below, but still faster than `FoldList` in a number of cases.

---

If the resets are fairly sparse it is possible to beat the `FoldList` method by accumulating, then setting first zeros in the original list to appropriate negative values based on that pass, then accumulating again.  As a proof of concept implemented only for resetting on zeros:

```
fn2[a_List] := Module[{x = a, acc = Accumulate@a, pos},
   pos = Split[#, # + 1 == #2 &][[All, 1]] & @
     SparseArray[Unitize@x, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"];
   x[[pos]] = -Differences @ Prepend[acc[[pos]], 0];
   Accumulate @ x
 ]
```

***Edit:*** Adopting a method similar to my answer from [Find continuous sequences inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/find-continuous-sequences-inside-a-list/23623#23623) this method is faster than the OP on rather more frequent splits as well:

```
fn3[a_List] :=
 Module[{x = a, acc = Accumulate@a, pos},
   pos = SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] &[
     Subtract[1, Unitize@x]*
      Prepend[Unitize@Differences@x, 1]
     ];
   x[[pos]] = -Differences @ Prepend[acc[[pos]], 0];
   Accumulate @ x
 ]
```

I named your function `fn1`.  The `timeAvg` code has been posted *many* times.

On a list that resets on average **one in ten elements**:

```
big = RandomInteger[9, 1*^6];

Accumulate[big] // timeAvg
fn1[big, 0]     // timeAvg
fn2[big]        // timeAvg
fn3[big]        // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.004624
>
> 0.0656
>
> 0.0748
>
> 0.02808
> ```

Here `fn3` is more than twice as fast as your original.
Now with resets on average **one in one thousand elements**:

```
big = RandomInteger[999, 1*^6];
(* other lines the same *)
```

> ```
> 0.004496
>
> 0.0718
>
> 0.01248
>
> 0.0156
> ```

Here both `fn2` and `fn3` are several times faster than the original, but now `fn3` is slightly slower than `fn2`.  With increasingly sparse resets `fn2` continues to improve over `fn3`.

Comment: Just woke - I had pursued the very same idea of double accumulates, found it slower (at least on v9.x), will cut-n-paste your version and test. Yes, both fn2/fn3 considerably slower, regardless of sparsity.

Comment: +1 though for idea of course, appreciate the feedback as always!

Comment: @rasher Sorry I couldn't be of help. :-/

Answer (score 9):

For brevity:

```
Map[Accumulate, Split[test, #2!=0&]] // Flatten
```

> {0, 2, 4, 47839287, 47839289, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0}

... but not as fast as the OP :)

[ Thanks to MrWizard, changed `SplitBy` to `Split` which is more efficient ]

Comment: For what it's worth this is shorter and faster: `Join @@ Accumulate /@ Split[test, #2 != 0 &]`

Comment: `Join @@` is also faster than `Flatten` on packed arrays. :-) +1 by the way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As they say: "If you can't flatten them, join them"

Comment: Actually that doesn't matter because `Split` does not produce packed sublists!  For some reason I falsely remembered that it did.

Comment: Thanks for reply - this is basically same as my original method, as you noted, clean but gets slow on huge lists. +1