# Sisyphus Random Walk

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

A Sisyphus Random Walk evolves as follows: With probability (r) you advance the position of the walker by +1. With probability (1-r) the walker resets at x0 = 0.

To simulate the probability of reset I use a Bernoulli Distribution:

```
t =  Prepend[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.7], 9],0]
{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

According to this distribution the walk should evolve as follows:

```
srw = {0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,3,4}
```

I am unsure what functions I should use to get the desired output.

Comment: closely related: [Faster “stuttering” accumulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47296/125)

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to use a geometric and just append "ranges" of length given by the geometric variates?

Comment: This is quite a bit off topic, but I still wonder: why it is called a Sisyphus random walk, not a Sisyphean random walk?

Comment: @kglr Why not a duplicate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, not sure but (although getting `srw` from `t` is a special case of the linked q/a) this one seems to have more emphasis on the random process (and most of the answers seem to focus on that aspect). Maybe Will can clarify.

Comment: @kglr I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the Faster "stuttering" accumulate question. In a Sisyphus random walk the resetting is a stochastic process. The programming behind this is very similar however. And yes, srw is one randomly generated case where the reset probability is 0.3.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can iterate with `FoldList`:

```
data = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};

FoldList[#2 * (#1 + #2)&, data]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Another approach is to accumulate consecutive runs of `1`:

```
Join @@ Accumulate /@ Split[data]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Comment: Love the simplicity of the second method.

Comment: for amusement: `FoldList[+###2&, data]`

Comment: #crazy${}$${}$${}$

Answer (score 10):

A nice problem. Why not solve it analytically?

Let us use Latex to formulate the problem and write down the solution, and then move to Mathematica. Finally we discuss the results and generalizations.

**Part 1: mathematical formulation of the problem**

Let $w(t,k)$ be the probability that at time t(>=0) the walker is at position k.

Then let us derive the evolution equations. We do it carefully now because previously I had made an error here.

For $k>0$ we have the balance

$\begin{align}
w(t+1,k) 
&=w(t,k)& \text{(old value)}\\ 
&-(1-r)w(t,k)& \text{(loss to 0)}\\
&- r\; w(t,k) &\text{(loss to k+1)}\\
&+ r\; w(t,k-1)& \text{(gain from k-1)}\\
\end{align}$

this gives the equation

$$w(t+1,k) = r\; w(t,k-1), \;\;\;\;\;t\ge0, k\gt0\tag{1}$$

This is a partial recursion equation.

Remark: In the continuos aprroximation to first order

$$w(t+1,k) \simeq w(t,k) + \frac{\partial w(t,k)}{\partial t}$$
$$w(t,k-1) \simeq w(t,k) - \frac{\partial w(t,k)}{\partial k}$$

(1) turns into this linear partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial w(t,k)}{\partial t}+ r \frac{\partial w(t,k)}{\partial k}-(1-r) w(t,k)=0 \tag{1a}$$

For $k=0$ we have the balance

$\begin{align}
w(t+1,0) 
&=w(t,0)& \text{(old value)}\\ 
&- r\; w(t,0) &\text{(loss to 1)}\\
&+ (1-r) \left(w(t,1)+w(t,2)+...\right)&\text{(gain 0 from all others)}\\
\end{align}$

This gives

$$w(t+1,0) = (1-r) \sum_{k=0}^\infty w(t,k)$$

Now, the sum is the total probability that the walker is somewhere which is, of course, equal to 1, which greatly simplifies to the simple equation

$$w(t,0) = (1-r), t>0$$

valid for $t>0$.

The complete solution for k=0 is

$$w(t,0) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll} 
(1-r) & t \geq 1 \\ 
w_{0} & t = 0 \\ 
0 & t < 0 \\  \end{array} \right. \tag{2}$$

Here $w_{0}$ is the starting probability at $k=0$.

Notice that weh must have either $w_{0}=1$ (walker starts in the origin) or $w_{0}=0$ (walker starts not in the origin but somewhere else).

In order to finalize the formulation of the problem we need initial conditions as well as boundary conditions.

*initial conditions*

We assume that the walker at $t=0$ is in location $k=n\ge0$, i.e.

$$w(0,k)=\delta_{k,n}\tag{3}$$

where $\delta_{k,n}$ is the Kronecker symbol defined as unity if $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise.

*boundary condition*

The problem is one-sided, hence we request that

$$w(t,k<0) = 0\tag{4}$$

for all times $t>=0$.

**Part 2: solution (with Mathematica)**

For the sake of brevity I provide here the solution as an Mathematica expression without derivation.

The probability w[t, k, r, n] for a walker starting at location $k=n$ at time $t$ and location $k$ is given by

```
w[t_, k_, r_, n_] := 
 r^t KroneckerDelta[t, k - n]                       (4)
+ (1 - r) r^k Boole[0 <= k <= t - 1]
```

This a sum of two terms: the term with the KroneckerDelta corresponds to the initial position, and the second term describes the development starting from the origin. The latter starts automatically with the first jump for $t=1$.

We define the state of our system at a given time as the vector of the probabilities

$$w(t) = (w(t,0), w(t,1), ..., w(t,k_{max}))$$

The time development of the state is then given by

```
ta[r_, n_] := Table[w[t, k, r, n], {t, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 8}]
```

Example 1: walker starts at $k=0$

```
 ta[1/2, 0] // Column;
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 \{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,0,0,0,0,0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},0,0,0,0,0,0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},0,0,0,0,0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{16},0,0,0,0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{32},\frac{1}{32},0,0,0\right\} \\
\end{array}$

Example 2: walker starts at $k=3$

```
ta[1/2, 3] // Column;
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 \{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},0,0,0,\frac{1}{2},0,0,0,0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},0,0,0,\frac{1}{4},0,0,0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},0,0,0,\frac{1}{8},0,0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},0,0,0,\frac{1}{16},0\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{32},0,0,0,\frac{1}{32}\right\} \\
\end{array}$

The structure of the solution is easily grasped from the two examples.

A 3D visualization could be done using this table

```
 tb[r_, n_] := 
      Flatten[Table[{t, k, f[t, k, r, n]}, {k, 0, 8}, {t, 0, 5}], 1];

With[{r = 1/2, n = 3}, 
 ListPlot3D[tb[r, n], Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Sysiphos random walk for r=" <> ToString[r, InputForm] <> 
    " starting at k=" <> ToString[n] <> 
    "\nProbability w(t,k) for k>0 as a function of time", 
  PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"k", "t", "w(t,k)"}]]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm not able to rotate the graph to a more revealing orientation (a hint is greatly appreciated).

**Derivation**

(work in progress)

*case k=0*

No calculation is necessary because (2) already gives the solution which is constant for $t\gt0$.

This result is independent of the specific starting point of the walker: if he would start at $k=0$ then, for t=1 he jumps to $k=1$ with probability $r$ which means that he remains at $k=0$ with probability $1-r$. If he starts at any other location he jumps back to $0$ in the next tmes step with probability $(1-r)$, hence we obtain the same result.

*case k>0*.

Using Mathematica to solve the recursion (1) led me to a wrong solution (see below).

However, knowing $w(t,0)$ from (2) we can proceed easily as follows.

For $k=1$ we have

$$w(t,1)=r w(t-1,0) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll} 
r(1-r) & t \gt 1 \\ 
r w_{0} & t = 1 \\ 
0 & t < 1 \\  \end{array} \right.$$

for $k=2$

$$w(t,2)=r w(t-1,1) =r w(t-2,0)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll} 
r^2(1-r) & t \gt 2 \\ 
r^2 w_{0} & t = 2 \\ 
0 & t < 2 \\  \end{array} \right.$$

and so on, and in general

$$w(t,k)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll} 
r^k(1-r) & t \gt k \\ 
r^k w_{0} & t = k \\ 
0 & t < k \\  \end{array} \right.\tag{4}$$

(4) is the solution. It is even valid for $k=0$.

For the initial value we have from (4)

$$w(0,k)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll} 
r^k(1-r) & 0 \gt k \\ 
r^k w_{0} & 0 = k \\ 
0 & 0 < k \\  \end{array} \right.\tag{5}$$

The following text is still to be corrected.

*Mathematica in action*

We have from (1)

```
sol = RSolve[w[t + 1, k] == r w[t, k - 1], w[t, k], {t, k}]

(* Out[43]= {{w[t, k] -> r^(-1 + t) C[1][k - t]}} *)
```

The somewhat strange looking expression of the constant `C[1]` with an argument means just a an arbitrary function $f(k-t)$

In order to find $f$ we consider the initial condition at time $t=1$ and compare

$$r^0 f(k - 1) = r \delta_{1,k} + r\delta_{n+1,k}$$

which gives

$$w(t,k) = r^t (1-r)\delta_{0,k->k-t} + r^t\delta_{n,k->k-t}$$

...

**Part 3: discussion**

Just a sketch, to be completed and expanded

*Asymptotic behaviour for large times*

Next question: what is the asymptotic shape of the spatial profile? That is what is $w(t\to\infty,k)$ as a function of $k$?

My feeling tells me that is should be exponential ... like the pressure in the atmosphere.

Let's look at it qualitatively: if there were no jumping back, the walker would move away to $k\to\infty$ indefinitely. The jumping back leads to renewed filling from below of, in principle, any position.

What about $w(t,1)$? Let us try to calculate it exactly. (DONE)

Comment: Something seems wrong to me. After one time step, the probability to be at the origin (k=0) is 1/2. After a second time step, half of that amount (0.25) is at k=1.  That large a probability should be visible on the graph. What am I missing?  And could you include k=0 in the above plot?

Comment: @Kieran Mullen Ooops, I'll check it.

Comment: @Kieran Mullen: you are right, I was wrong. Thanks a lot for pointing this out. Thinking more thouroughly I find for a walker starting at $k=0$ that $w(t<k)=0$, $w(t=k) = 1/2^k$, and $w(t>k)=1/2^{k+1}$. Hence the asymptotic profile is indeed exponential. Need to revise my work, not sure which part of it I can save.

Comment: If you're interested in the properties of these types of random walks, I'd recommend "Sisyphus Random Walk" by Montero and Villarroel: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09239

Comment: @Will Thank you very much for the hint. I'll look at it when I'm finished with my solution

Answer (score 7):

Another approach would be to formulate this as a `DiscreteMarkovProcess`.  Since `DiscreteMarkovProcess` only allows a finite state space, we need to truncate at some large distance `xmax`.  Also note that the first state is 1, not 0.

```
xmax = 100;
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, SparseArray[Join[
  Table[{x, x + 1} -> r, {x, xmax - 1}],
  Table[{x, 1} -> 1 - r, {x, xmax}]]]];
```

To simulate:

```
r = 0.9;
ListPlot[RandomFunction[proc, {0, 200}], AxesLabel -> {t, x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An advantage of this approach is you can use Mathematica's machinery for such processes.  For example, the stationary distribution is easy to compute:

```
DiscretePlot[Evaluate@PDF[StationaryDistribution[proc, x],
  {x, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, p[x]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Just playing around, the number of 1's before a 0 is defined by the NegativeBinomial distribution, so we can create some random walk data that way. Kind of kludgy but sort of interesting. Depends on what you are trying to get out of the simulation.

Define a distribution for the number of sequential $1$'s before a single $0$, where the probability of a $0$ is $0.3$.

```
nbd = NegativeBinomialDistribution[1, .3]
```

Generate some data

```
dat = Table[RandomVariate[nbd], {10}]

(* {2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3} *)
```

Create a function to explode the peak sizes into sequence of steps, putting a $0$ onto the ends of just the nonzero values.

```
rang[0] = 0;
rang[x_] := {Range[x], 0}
```

Map this over the data and flatten it.

```
Map[rang, dat] // Flatten
```

> {1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3,
>     0}

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $k_0=0$ with probability 1, the probability that $k_t=0$ at some time $t>0$ is $1-r$.  If $k_t=k$ where $t\geq k$, then $k_{t-k}$ must have been zero.  Therefore the general solution must be

$$Pr(k_t=k)=Pr(k_{t-k}=0)\times Pr(k \text{ consecutive successes})=(1-r)p^k$$

for $t\geq k\geq 0$ and $t>0$.  This is just a negative binomial distribution.