# Automatic placement of legend box with Placed[] (equivalent to "best" in matplotlib)

Tags: plotting, legending

When I create plots, I usually make a legend box which I then manually have to place within the plot using the Placed[] option. However, since it is manual, it means that I always need to adjust it or I will risk covering a part of the plot, something that often happens when I batch produce plots. I would therefore like to have an Automatic option, similar to the "best" placement type in Python matplotlib, that puts the legend within the plot, but not covering anything. If I simply use "Automatic", Mathematica will place the legend outside of the plot to the right, but this is often a waste of space.

Example:

```
ListPlot[{
  Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 10}],
  Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0, 10}]
  }
 , ImageSize -> 1000,
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    Map[Style[#, FontSize -> 24, 
       FontFamily -> "TimesNewRoman"] &, {"sin", "cos"}], 
    Spacings -> {0.15, -0.2}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5, 
        FrameStyle -> Gray, Background -> White] &)]
   , Scaled[{0.87, 0.75}]]
 ]
```

[image: plotExample]

I guess that one option would be to make a custom function that, from the input data, determines the plot range, finds the biggest empty space in the plot, and then uses these coordinates for the Placed[] option. However, I think that this will require a lot of tweaking, to accomodate for 1) a varying number of entries in the legend and 2) the feature in Mathematica where the shape of the legend box can vary depending on placement and number of entries.

It would also not be very "pretty" to simply use the biggest white space -- often the upper right corner is large enough even though it might not be the biggest white space, and when it is large enough, it should take precedence.

Comment: This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/220676/9469) addresses very similar problem, however, the accepted solution does not work out of the box. Some adjustments are needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
legend = LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], 
   Map[Style[#, FontSize -> 24, Magenta, FontFamily -> "TimesNewRoman"] &, 
      {"sin", "cos", "blah", "blah", "blah"}], 
   Spacings -> {0.15, 1}, LegendMarkers -> Automatic, 
   LegendFunction -> 
       (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5, FrameStyle -> Cyan, Background -> None] &)];

lp = ListPlot[{Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 10}], 
    Table[{i, Cos[i]}, {i, 0, 10}]}, ImageSize -> 1000, 
   Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> None, Axes -> False];

Legended[Show[lp, FrameTicks -> Automatic], 
 Placed[legend, Scaled[{0.87, 0.75}]]]
```

[image]

```
legenddims = Rasterize[legend, "RasterSize"];
```

[Binarize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binarize.html) and [dilate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html) `lp` with a kernel that depends on `legenddims`:

```
dilatedimage = ColorNegate @
    Dilation[ColorNegate@Binarize[lp], ConstantArray[1, Reverse@legenddims]];

Overlay[{dilatedimage, lp}]
```

[image]

If the legend is centered in any of the white pixels it will not touch the plot lines.

Centroids of the polygons as candidate positions for the legend:

```
centroids = RegionCentroid /@ MeshPrimitives[ImageMesh[dilatedimage], 2];

preferredposition = ImageDimensions @ lp (* top-right corner *)
```

The scaled position closest to `preferredposition`:

```
legendposition = First @ 
   Nearest[centroids, preferredposition, 1] / ImageDimensions[lp]
```

> ```
> {0.942151, 0.804216}
> ```

```
Legended[Show[lp, FrameTicks -> Automatic], Placed[legend, legendposition]]
```

[image]

```
preferredposition = {0, 0};  (* bottom-left corner *)  

legendposition = First @ 
   Nearest[centroids, preferredposition, 1] / ImageDimensions[lp]
```

> ```
> {0.0989771, 0.265792}
> ```

```
Legended[Show[lp, FrameTicks -> Automatic], Placed[legend, legendposition]]
```

[image]

Pick a random point in `ImageMesh[dilatedimage]` to place the legend:

```
SeedRandom[7777]

Legended[Show[lp, FrameTicks -> Automatic], 
 Placed[legend,RandomPoint[ImageMesh[dilatedimage]] / ImageDimensions[lp]]]
```

[image]

Dilated/binarized image and legend positions:

```
DynamicModule[{loc = {0, 0}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic @ loc, 
  Overlay[{dilatedimage, lp}], 
  Appearance -> legend]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is really cool and works even better than I imagined. Thank you so much! I need to wait 12 hours to award you the bounty.

Comment: Very nice. Some other ideas to find centers: `PixelValuePositions[Pruning[MaxDetect[DistanceTransform[DeleteSmallComponents[dilatedimage]]]], 1]` or `ComponentMeasurements[DeleteSmallComponents[dilatedimage], "Medoid"]`.

Comment: Also it might make more sense to use `ConnectedMeshComponents` instead of `MeshPrimitives`. Compare: `reg = DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[Disk[], Disk[{3, 0}]]];

Length /@ {MeshPrimitives[reg, 2], ConnectedMeshComponents[reg]}`