# Cases vs Select, Pattern vs Pure function

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, pure-function

What is the difference between having `Cases` with selection condition presented by pattern and `a` with pure function as condition? What are the internal implementational reasons to have them separate?

As a side question: How can I select from a list of integers those that have a difference with their neighbor ( left or right, or both) unity?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your first case? It's related to the second?

Comment: Regarding the side question also see: [(23607)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any `criteria` (used for `Select`) can be written as the pattern _?(criteria) (used for `Cases` or `DeleteCases`). For single argument functions, the pure function can be abbreviated

```
list = Range[20];

Select[list, EvenQ[#] &] ==
 Select[list, EvenQ] ==
 Cases[list, _?(EvenQ[#] &)] ==
 Cases[list, _?EvenQ] ==
 DeleteCases[list, _?(! EvenQ[#] &)] ==
 DeleteCases[list, _?(OddQ[#] &)] ==
 DeleteCases[list, _?OddQ] ==
 Pick[list, EvenQ[list]] ==
 Range[2, 20, 2]
```

> True

Answer (score 5):

For the second part of question:

(*n.b.*: If you want positions instead of elements, change `#[[Union[p - 1, p]]]` to `Union[p - 1, p]`.)

```
With[{p = Pick[Range@Length@#, Abs[Differences@Prepend[#, #[[1]] - 2]], 1]},
              #[[Union[p - 1, p]]]] &@theList
```

This will be *much* faster on larger lists then the solution based on `Split` from *Alexey Popkov* (which I up-voted - it's canonical and clean).

Answer (score 5):

This is aimed at the first part of your question. I do not claim it is exhaustive.

`Cases` and `Select` behave differently in many situations.

Things `Cases` can do that `Select` can't

- take a level specification
- match and replace.
- take an argument limiting the number of matches it returns

`Cases` and `Select` treat associations differently.

```
assoc = <|a -> 1, b -> 2|>;
assoc // Cases[_?(# > 1 &)]
```

> ```
> {2}
> ```

```
assoc // Select[# > 1 &]
```

> ```
> <|b -> 2|>
> ```

Comment: Actually already in *Mathematica* 5 `Select` accepts third argument limiting the number of matches it returns, so your third statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

For your second question

> How can I select from a list of integers those that have a difference with their neighbor ( left or right, or both) unity?

you could use:

```
lst = RandomInteger[10, 10]
Flatten@Select[Split[lst, Abs[#1 - #2] == 1 &], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

> ```
> {8, 7, 5, 7, 0, 7, 6, 1, 1, 2}
>
> {8, 7, 7, 6, 1, 2}
> ```