# Simple exercise using the function Cases

Tags: list-manipulation, prime-numbers

I'm having some trouble in the following exercise:

Find which elements of the list are prime numbers or divisible by 3.

```
list = Table[i^2 - 6 i - 1, {i, 0, 15}]
```

my attempt: `Cases[list, Divisible[_,3]]`. *Mathematica* didn't like this and I don't know how to write it correctly :/

For prime numbers, I used `Cases[list, _?PrimeQ]` and it gave me the right answer, but I can't imagine a way to use incorporate the "or" thing, except by using a `If`. Is there a more imperative way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `Select[]` might be more straightforward for you.

Comment: `Cases[list,x_/;Or@@{Divisible[x,3],PrimeQ[x]}]`

Comment: You can also define your test and use it as you did `PrimeQ` `myTest[x]:=Or@@{Divisible[x,3],PrimeQ[x]}; Cases[list,_?myTest]`

Comment: You might find the answers to [(91180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91180/) and its linked duplicates of use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Culling elements from lists may done several ways, such as with `Cases`, `Select`, and `Pick`.  [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) and [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) seem quite similar when culling elements from level 1.  The documentation for `Select` shows that the following are equivalent:

```
Select[list, f]
Cases[list, x_ /; f[x]]
```

This, too, is equivalent:

```
Cases[list, _?f]
```

The functions [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (`/;`) and [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) (`?`) are ways to restrict a pattern to match only expressions that both match the pattern and satisfy a (boolean) condition.

Let's turn to the exercise at hand: To use `Cases` to do the following.

> Find which elements of the list are prime numbers or divisible by 3.

I like the expressiveness of `Condition`, if you read `/;` as "such that" or "that", so I'll try that.  We can map the elements of the problem to elements of code if we mangle the order slightly:

```
(* Find            *)   Cases[
(* in the list     *)    list,
(* the elements    *)    x_ 
(* that are        *)     /;
(* either          *)     Or[
(*  prime or       *)      PrimeQ[x],
(*  divisible by 3 *)      Divisible[x, 3]
                         ]]

(*  {-6, -9, -9, -6, 6, 15, 39, 54, 71, 90, 111}  *)
```

Or more succinctly,

```
Cases[list, x_ /; PrimeQ[x] || Divisible[x, 3]]
```

Comment: **Addendum**: for a sufficiently long list, exploiting the short-circuit property of `Or[]` can be helpful: test for divisibility by $3$ first, since it's the easier test, and invoke the primality test only if that fails. So, `x_ /; Divisible[x, 3] || PrimeQ[x]`

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I'm not completely familiar with internals, but tests show `PrimeQ` is faster than `Divisible[#, 3]&` for small integers.  (`PrimeQ /@ Range@n` vs. `Divisible[#, 3] & /@ Range@n` -- 30% faster when `n < 10^6`; 13% for `n = 10^7, 10^8`, though `10^8` seemed to exercise memory management.)

Comment: Huh, that's very odd (yet another case of slow new functions?). What if the less idiomatic `Mod[#, 3] == 0 &` was used instead?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  `Divisible` is 1/3 faster than `Mod`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. A partial explanation is that `PrimeQ` is really fast on even integers.  On odd integers `PrimeQ` is faster (average `1 <= x <= n`) up to `n = 10^7` and then `Divisible` starts to edge it out.

Comment: Very interesting. Intuitively, I'd thought that Miller-Rabin is certainly more elaborate than computing a remainder, but I guess `PrimeQ[]` might actually be doing sonething else behind the scenes before Miller-Rabin kicks in, which might account for your observations.

Answer (score 4):

Many possible approaches.  One is

```
Union[Cases[list, _?PrimeQ], Cases[list, i_ /; Mod[i, 3] == 0]]
(* {-9, -6, 6, 15, 39, 54, 71, 90, 111} *)
```

**Addendum**

If, instead, you want the elements in order and with their corresponding `i` values

```
Flatten@Union[Position[list, _?PrimeQ], Position[list, i_ /; Mod[i, 3] == 0]]
list[[%]]
(* {2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15} 
   {-6, -9, -9, -6, 6, 15, 39, 54, 71, 90, 111} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with the hint from @Guess who i is:

```
Select[list, Divisible[#, 3] &]~Union~Select[list, PrimeQ]
{-9, -6, 6, 15, 39, 54, 71, 90, 111}
```

Comment: I had `Select[list, Divisible[#, 3] || PrimeQ[#] &]` in mind, tho.

Comment: @Guess who it is My first attempt, but today is sunday and it would not correctly work. Farther, I'm sure, I have typed the "t" in your name. I believe, it is tipped over. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most near your attempt:

```
Cases[list, _?(Divisible[#, 3] &)]
```

no `x_` :p

what you write is a *pattern*, use `_?` make boolean into a pattern.

put together:

```
Cases[list, _?((Divisible[#, 3] || PrimeQ[#]) &)]
```