# Whats the difference between Cases and Select?

Tags: performance-tuning, coding-style

Im trying to further my understanding of mathematica coding and came up across this question. What is the main difference between `Cases` and `Select`?

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, 10^4];
Cases[data, {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b} /; c > 0]
Select[data, #[[3]] > 0 &][[All, ;; 2]]
```

Both these approaches give the same result, Im just curious about the benefits of each. When is `Select` superior to `Cases` and vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What best practices or performance considerations are there for choosing between Cases, Position, Pick and Select?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2/13). Also this: [Cases vs Select, Pattern vs Pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91180/13)

Comment: How about `Pick[data, UnitStep[data[[All, 3]]], 1]` for speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cases` uses patterns, `Select` uses testing functions. Because of this, `Select` is not seldomly faster because it reduces pattern matching to the very least: Does the testing function evaluate to `True` or not? (Pattern matching can be a real bottleneck sometimes, inparticular if the mere *check* for matching enforces [unpacking of arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496).)

On the other hand, `Cases` is much more flexible.

1.) `Cases` allows a level specification. (`Select` always operates on the first level of an expression)

2.) `Cases` allows to apply replacement rules immediately.

Comment: Thanks @Alan. It was a typo.