# Timing and memory use is critical:fast partitioning of binary sparse array

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays, partitions

I do experiments were I measure a signal, and I need to know at what time points it is above a threshold.  If at a given time point, the signal is above the threshold, then a '1' gets put into the array otherwise the value is zero.  This effectively generates a binary signal.

A `SparseArray` is a natural solution to this because I want to conserve memory because the data can be quite large.  For example, 1000 raw signals, each with 60,000 to 100,000 time points.

After putting the data into a `SparseArray`, I want split the array into groups of 1's and get the positions where the Array was split.

In a simple example I make a sparse array that represents 20 seconds of time

```
 lowArray = 
  SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 20]


ListPlot[lowArray, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Plot]

I would like the output to be two lists.  One which contains the splits and one that contains the positions

```
 splits = { {1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1};
 pos = {{1,5},{10,11}, {15,20}}
```

This question is similar to [Find Continuous Sequences Inside a List](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/find-continuous-sequences-inside-a-list/23608#23608), 
but `Split` does not work on a `SparseArray`.  Also, its not clear to me how to get the positions where the array was split.

Solutions do not have to use a `SparseArray`, but it is my preference because the data can be quite large.  However if this can be done faster not using a `SparseArray', the faster method will be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pos={First@#,Last@#}&/@Split[Flatten@lowArray["NonzeroPositions"],#2-#1==1&]
```

> `{{1,5},{10,11},{15,20}}`

```
splits=lowArray[[Range@@#]]&/@pos//Normal
```

> `{{1,1,1,1,1},{1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1}}`