# Determine repeating number of a given number and corresponding position

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

For instance, the data is as follows:

```
data = {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1}
```

The target output when determining how many times `"1"` repeats should be:

```
{{1, 3}, {6, 2}}
```

with the `1` showing that the first set of repetitions begins at position `1` in the list and the `3` showing that `"1"` occurs `3` times. The `6` shows that the second set of repetitions begins in the sixth position of the list and the `"1"` occurs twice.

Comment: How do we know that you're seeking the positions and length of $1$s, and not $-1$s?

Comment: I apologize for any confusion I may have caused, David. I did mean 1s and not -1s. I should have used 1s and 0s in the example, but andre's response gives me the output I required.

Edit: Batracos, your suggestion doesn't seem to give me the output I'm looking for. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [(116085)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116085/121).  Also related: [(23607)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121), [(117859)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117859/121)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, Mr. Wizard. I didn't come across those in my search but they offer some elegant ways to solve the problem. Also, thank you to everyone who provided a solution! I do not fully comprehend how all of the solutions work, but they give me something to learn about!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this question may still be considered a duplicate of [Finding negative sequences in a large list: optimization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116085/121) but it seems to permit a somewhat simpler solution which I would like to post.

This is still written for performance over brevity.  I shall benchmark it later if I remember.

```
fn[a_List, n_] :=
  Module[{p, q, r},
    p = Pick[Range @ Length @ a, Unitize[n - a], 1];
    q = Prepend[p + 1, 1];
    r = Append[p, Length@a + 1] - q;
    Pick[{q, r}\[Transpose], Unitize @ r, 1]
  ]
```

Example:

```
data = {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1};

fn[data, 1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {6, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 14):

If you have Mma version >= 10.1 , this does the job :

```
data = {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1};
{First[#], Last[#] - First[#] + 1} & /@ SequencePosition[data, {Repeated[1]}, Overlaps -> False]
```

In terms of speed, this solution is catastrophic. See studies in other answers.

Answer (score 9):

```
{#1, Length[{##}]} & @@@ Split[PositionIndex[data][1], #2 - #1 == 1 &]
{#1, Length[{##}]} & @@@ Split[Pick[Range@Length@data, 1 - Unitize[1 - data], 1], #2 - #1 == 1 &]
```

Answer (score 8):

This one's just for fun, kind of a reverse-codegolf

```
i = 1;
Reap[Scan[(Sow[{First@#, i, Length@#}]; i += Length[#];) &, 
   Split[data]]] // Cases[#, {1, x__} :> {x}, Infinity] &
(* {{1, 3}, {6, 2}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Position[]` and `Split[_, #2 - #1 == 1 &]`

```
data = {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1};

(*
   Flatten@Position[data, 1]
   {1, 2, 3, 6, 7}
*)

{First@#, Length@#} & /@ 
  Split[Flatten@Position[data, 1], #2 - #1 == 1 &]
(* {{1, 3}, {6, 2}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that I'm late to the party, yet another one-liner:

```
Thread[{Most@Prepend[Accumulate@# + 1, 1], #}][[3/2-data[[1]]/2;; ;; 2]] &[Length /@ Split@data]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a variant of Jason B answer (because I enjoy `Reap` and `Sow`):

```
Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2[[1]], #1] &, data], 
  1, {First@#, Length@#} & /@ Split[#2, #2 - #1 == 1 &] &][[-1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

`ReplaceRepeated` version, inefficient as it frequently is.

```
SeedRandom[1];
test = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 20]
```

> `{1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1 ... 1, 1, 1}`

```
(Reverse[Append[1] /@ Position[test, 1]] //.
   {x___, {a_, b_}, {c_, 1}, y___} /; a == c + 1 :>
    {x, {c, b + 1}, y}) // Reverse
```

> `{{1, 2}, {4, 1}, {8, 1}, {10, 1}, {18, 3}}`

Answer (score 3):

Seeing an answer from andre using [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) but remembering that [it can be slow with patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121) I wanted to test a String alternative.  For this answer I shall assume that your list is always composed of `1` and `-1` and you are searching for `1`, just to keep the code a bit shorter.  If not `Unitize` can be used as demonstrated earlier.  Alternatively a different offset could be used before [`FromCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCharacterCode.html) if the values in your input are not too large.

```
fn2[a_List] :=
 Module[{str, pos},
   str = FromCharacterCode[a + 96];
   pos = StringPosition[str, "a" .., Overlaps -> False];
   If[pos === {}, Return[{}]];
   {#, #2 - # + 1}\[Transpose] & @@ (pos\[Transpose])
 ]
```

This is slower than my first method but it is *much* faster than `SequencePosition`:

```
x = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 2*^3];

fn[x, 1]; // RepeatedTiming

fn2[x];   // RepeatedTiming

SequencePosition[x, {1 ..}, Overlaps -> False]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0000665, Null}
>
> {0.000263, Null}
>
> {10.79, Null}
> ```