# Easy way to covert a Range or set of vales to an Interval object

Tags: list-manipulation, intervals

I am generating data such as {4,5,6,7,8,9,20,21,22,23,24,25,78,79,90}.  This list can reach thousands of elements.  Is there a simple or good method to convert such a list into a set on Interval objects which would be much shorter and manageable.

Thanks

Comment: What is an interval object?

Comment: Mathematica has the function Interval[1,5] which is equivalent to {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: According to the documentation it is NOT equivalent to that, but, rather, is the closed interval from $1$ to $5,$ so my question stands. Intervals do not appear to be the same as ranges...

Comment: Well yes they are not equivalent but the answer that I am looking for would from the example {Interval[4,9],Interval[20,25],Interval[78,79],Interval[90,90]}.  I am not for this case interested in interval arithmetic just a representation.  For the cases where there are thousands of elements the number of intervals would be about 10-20 which i much easier to analyze for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this?

```
S = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 78, 79, 90};
consec = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &;
DS = SequenceCases[S, {_, __}?consec];
Table[{First@DS[[i]], Last@DS[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@DS}]
```

this one is better

```
S = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 78, 79, 90};
{Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Split[S, #2 - #1 == 1 &]
```

Comment: Very nice, I was not at all thinking in this direction, however I note that it misses the last single case of 90.

Comment: yes... I guess there is a problem if you are having single cases...

Comment: Well, I can detect that and add it to the list afterwards.  The solution is really neat.  Thanks.

Comment: see this.  list = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 78, 79, 90};
{Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Split[list, #2 - #1 == 1 &]

Comment: See [`MinMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html).

Comment: Testing your first version when there are about 10,000 numbers involved expanded my memory to over 40 GB then crashed.  The internal accounting looks to be combintorial in nature.  The second method takes no noticeable memory and is completed in seconds.

Comment: @Jenny_mathy i think the same approach was used by Simon Woods to solve one question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the simplest I can think of:

```
foo[l_, x_] := Module[{ll = l[[-1, -1]]},
  If[ll + 1 == x, Append[l[[;; -2]], Append[l[[-1]], x]],
   Append[l, {x}]]]

z[l_] := Fold[foo, {{l[[1]]}}, Rest[l]]

makeInt[l_] := int[#[[1]], #[[-1]]] & /@ z[l]
```

(notice that I am not using `Interval`, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You may use methods from [Find continuous sequences inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121), i.e. my `intervals`:

```
intervals[a_List] :=
 {a[[Prepend[# + 1, 1]]], a[[Append[#, -1]]]}\[Transpose] & @ 
  SparseArray[Differences @ a, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]

intervals[{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 78, 79, 90}]

Interval @@ %

NumberLinePlot[%]
```

> ```
> {{4, 9}, {20, 25}, {78, 79}, {90, 90}}
>
> Interval[{4, 9}, {20, 25}, {78, 79}, {90, 90}]
> ```

[image]