# Return last number in sub-sequences in a list of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, integer-sequence

Given a list of integers like this:

```
z = {113, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 475, 476, 529, 538, 542, 543, 544}
```

I want a function that returns:

```
{113, 121, 476, 529, 538, 544}
```

here's the pedestrian version:

```
LastinSequence[a_] := Module[
  {n},
  n = {};
  Do[
   If[
     a[[i]] > (1 + a[[i - 1]]),
     n = Append[n, a[[i - 1]]]
     ];
   , {i, 2, Length@a}
   ];
  n = Append[n, Last@a];
  n
  ]
```

Horrible.

**Can I have some suggestions to do this elegantly (and quickly!) in Wolfram language?**

Also, a variation `FirstinSequence[a_]` that would return:

```
{113 117, 475, 529, 538, 542}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/find-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers-inside-a-list, with some of the same techniques we see in the answers that have already been posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a "background" element of the desired difference in `SparseArray` on the differences, and `"AdjacencyLists"` will pick out what you desire:

Last in sequence:

```
positions = Append[SparseArray[Differences@z, Automatic, 1], 0]["AdjacencyLists"]
(*  {1, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13}  *)

z ~Part~ positions // Normal
(*  {113, 121, 476, 529, 538, 544}  *)
```

More efficient version:

```
Append[
 z ~Part~
   SparseArray[Rest@z - Most@z, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"],
 Last@z]
```

First in sequence:

```
Prepend[
 Reverse@z ~Part~
  Reverse[SparseArray[Rest@z - Most@z, Automatic, 1]]["AdjacencyLists"],
 First@z]
(*  {113, 117, 475, 529, 538, 542}  *)
```

My answer is similar to [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/4999) to [Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/find-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers-inside-a-list), which asks for the essentially same thing as the OP but with the output in a different form.

Comment: +1 This seems to be the fastest approach so far.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks.  `"AdjacencyLists"` and `"NonzeroPositions"` can be found in efficient solution to many similar problems on this site.  (I couldn't find a duplicate, though, which surprises me.)

Comment: @Shadowray Really?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KVWea.png

Comment: Note also that for vector of integers, `Differences[z]` may be noticably slower than `Rest[z]-Most[z]`

Comment: @Shadowray Awesome! I knew that but had forgotten. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelE2 How do you  access the documentation about   `"AdjacencyLists"` and `"NonzeroPositions" ` the way it's used in your answer ? If you hover with your cursor over these the information icon does not show up.

Comment: @SigisK Search this site. That's how I learned about them. You can also execute sa@"Properties" to see a list of such commands (where sa is a SparseArray)

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html):

```
Last /@ Split[z, #2 == # + 1&]
```

> {113, 121, 476, 529, 538, 544}

```
First /@ Split[z, #2 == # + 1&]
```

> {113, 117, 475, 529, 538, 542}

Comment: Very elegant indeed.

Answer (score 5):

`Pick` in combination with vectorized arithmetic is as fast as `SparseArray`:

```
myLastInSequenceV3[z_] := Join[Pick[Most[z], Unitize[Rest[z]-Most[z]-1], 1], {Last[z]}]
```

Alternative version. Shorter, but slower:

```
myLastInSequence[z_] := Pick[z, Join[Differences[z], {0}], Except[1, _Integer]]
```

Test:

```
LastinSequence[z] == myLastInSequence[z] == myLastInSequenceV3[z]
```

> True

Timing for `SparseArray`-based solution:

```
data = NestList[(# + RandomInteger[9]) &, 1, 100000];

lastInSequenceSparseUpd[z_] := Append[z ~Part~SparseArray[Rest@z - Most@z, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"],Last@z]
First@RepeatedTiming[lastInSequenceSparseUpd[data];]
```

> 0.0018

This method:

```
First@RepeatedTiming[myLastInSequenceV3[data];]
```

> 0.0019

Comment: Very fast and elegant. Superb!

Answer (score 4):

### Solutions

This is actually twice as fast as fast as kglr's but three times slower than Shadowray's . MichaelE2 has provided the fastest answer by far.

```
LastInSequenceRH2[d_] := Pick[d, Inner[Unequal, d, RotateLeft[d - 1], List]]
```

This was my previous attempt

```
FirstInSequenceRH1[z_] := With[{n = Length[z]},
   Pick[z, Array[(z[[#]] != z[[Max[# - 1, 1]]] + 1) &, n]]
   ];
LastInSequenceRH1[z_] := With[{n = Length[z]},
  Pick[z, Array[(z[[Min[# + 1, n]]] != z[[#]] + 1) &, n]]
  ]


FirstInSequence[data]
(* {113, 117, 475, 529, 538, 542} *)

LastInSequence[data]
(* {113, 121, 476, 529, 538, 544} *)
```

### Benchmark

```
data = NestList[(# + RandomInteger[9]) &, 1, 100000]; (* Large data       *)

First@RepeatedTiming[FirstInSequenceRH1[data];]       (* My first answer  *)
(* 0.242 *)

First@RepeatedTiming[FirstInSequencekglr[data];]      (* kglr's answer    *)
(* 0.0913 *)

First@RepeatedTiming[LastInSequenceOP[data];]         (* OP question      *)
(* 11.57 *)

First@RepeatedTiming[LastInSequenceRH2[data];]        (* My second answer *)
(* 0.049 *)

First@RepeatedTiming[LastInSequenceShadowray[data];]  (* Shadowray's      *)
(* 0.016 *)

First@RepeatedTiming[LastInSequenceMichaelE2[data];]  (* MichaelE2        *)
(* 0.0038 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some great solutions here.  I borrowed Shadowray's code and created this:

```
    FirstInSequence[z_] := 
 Join[{First[z]}, Pick[Rest[z], Unitize[Differences[z] - 1], 1]]

FirstInSequence[{113, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 475, 476, 529, 538, 
  542, 543, 544}]

{113, 117, 475, 529, 538, 542}
```