# How to pick consecutive numbers from list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap

Question is very simple.
If we have

```
tst = {2,3,4,6,7,9,11}
```

result must be

```
{{2,3,4}, {6,7}, {9}, {11}}
```

There are similar questions, but not exact.

My best solution is:

```
myFun[arr_] := Module[{prev = First@arr, tag = First@arr},
Reap[
 Sow[prev, tag];
 Do[
  If[prev != e - 1, tag = e];
  Sow[e, tag];
  prev = e,
  {e, Rest@tst}]
 ]][[2]];
```

Is it possible to do it better?

Comment: Related (but not identical): [Find subsequences of consecutive integers inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/106)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Split[]` was meant for this:

```
Split[{2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11}, #2 - #1 == 1 &]
   {{2, 3, 4}, {6, 7}, {9}, {11}}
```

Comment: `#2 - #1 == 1 &`   I was blind ((  Thank you!