# Index-based Array splitting

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I have an array of arbitrary elements, say strings:

```
testArray = {"String A", "String B", "String C", "String D", "String E"};
```

How can I split this into two arrays, one for the element with odd indices in `testArray` and one for elements with even indices in `testArray`:

```
testArrayOdd = {"String A", "String C", "String E"};
testArrayEven = {"String B", "String D"};
```

Is there a simple way to do this that generalizes to more complicated partitionings based on, say, the primeness of the index?

Clarification!: The strings in the array can be anything `"String 1"` could be `"knejibvei (junk)"`.  We only care about the INDEX of the string in the original array.  Sorry about this.  For odd / even testing of elements, see here: [Separate an array in two arrays, the even and odd terms being separated in these two arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20172/separate-an-array-in-two-arrays-the-even-and-odd-terms-being-separated-in-these?rq=1).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the simple case of even and odd, you can do either:

```
{testArrayOdd, testArrayEven} = {testArray[[;; ;; 2]], testArray[[2 ;; ;; 2]]}
(* {{"String 1", "String 3", "String 5"}, {"String 2", "String 4"}} *)
```

or

```
{testArrayOdd, testArrayEven} = Partition[testArray, 2, 2, 1, {}] ~Flatten~ {2}
```

For a more general grouping based on an arbitrary predicate, you can write a custom function:

```
Clear@groupByPositions
groupByPositions[list_, pred_] := 
    With[{trueList = testArray[[Select[Range@Length@list, pred]]]},
        {trueList, Complement[list, trueList]}
    ]
```

With this, the original problem becomes

```
{testArrayOdd, testArrayEven} = groupByPositions[testArray, OddQ]
```

and to group by prime indices:

```
groupByPositions[testArray, PrimeQ]
(* {{"String 2", "String 3", "String 5"}, {"String 1", "String 4"}} *)
```

Comment: Congratulations on the list-manipulation gold badge!

Comment: I didn't even realize you could use the third argument of `Flatten` that way. [Mind == blown](http://imgur.com/j74SykU).

Comment: Looks like you covered everything, and you even threw in some ~infix~ for me. +1

Comment: in your GroupByPositions code testArray should be 'list'.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of variety:

`MapIndexed` could be used here, in conjunction with tagged `Sow`ing and `Reap`ing:

```
Reap[MapIndexed[If[PrimeQ@First@#2, Sow[#1, 1], Sow[#1, 2]] &, 
   testArray]] // Last (* partition based on index primeness *)

(* {{"String 1", "String 4"}, {"String 2", "String 3", "String 5"}} *)
```

I've used the integers 1 and 2 as tags. (The docs show symbols like `x` and `y` being used, but integers appear to work OK too.)

The list associated with the first tag to be encountered is given first, hence the order of the sublists above. If you wished to change that, you could add `{2, 1}` as an extra argument at the end of `Reap`.

(As Mr. Wizard suggests in his comment, a better expression is:

```
Reap[MapIndexed[# ~Sow~ PrimeQ[#2] &, testArray]][[2]]
```

where the tag is automatically generated as the predicate's value and the `If` is completely avoided.)

Personally I find `GatherBy` most natural here:

```
Part[testArray, #] & /@ GatherBy[Range@Length@testArray, PrimeQ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the impression that Sow and Reap are really worth learning about.

Comment: Personally I feel that `Sow` and `Reap` are a bit of a throwback to procedural programming - not to say there aren't certain situations where they're useful, or that they aren't worth adding to your _Mathematica_ toolbox.

Comment: @CA30 In my opinion they are *very* worth learning about due to the flexibility of the abstraction and it's relatively high performance.  While e.g. `GatherBy` (added to the language after `Sow`/`Reap`) should be used where easily applicable as it will be both more concise and somewhat faster, `Sow` and `Reap` let you do things not otherwise possible without resorting to more verbose methods.

Comment: I can only comment that anything Mr.Wizard has to say about _Mathematica_ is worth heeding!

Comment: Thanks, Aky.  Incidentally I would write the `Sow`/`Reap` method like this:  `Reap[MapIndexed[# ~Sow~ PrimeQ[#2] &, testArray]][[2]]`.  You can also declare a specific order of output using the second parameter of `Reap`, e.g.: `Reap[MapIndexed[# ~Sow~ PrimeQ[#2] &, testArray], {True, False}][[2, All, 1]]`.  (This returns the prime-index elements in the first list rather than the second.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Something like that (i.e. generating the tag from the predicate itself) had crossed my mind at some point, and it's actually what made me think of `GatherBy`. I agree it's more elegant than manually assigning tags. Re your second point (about ordering the output) I mentioned that in my answer. (Unless I missed the point you're making.)

Comment: I see that you did mention that; sorry for overlooking it!  Anyway, you already have my +1.

Answer (score 4):

You could use my [`GatherByList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158637/45431) function to do this:

```
GatherByList[list_, representatives_] := Module[{func},
    func /: Map[func, _] := representatives;
    GatherBy[list, func]
]

GatherByList[testArray, EvenQ[Range @ Length @ testArray]]
GatherByList[testArray, PrimeQ[Range @ Length @ testArray]]
```

> {{"String A", "String C", "String E"}, {"String B", "String D"}}
>
> {{"String A", "String D"}, {"String B", "String C", "String E"}}

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[groupByIndex1, groupByIndex2]
groupByIndex1 = Function[{t}, Pick[#, #2 /@ (Range @ Length @ #), t]] /@ {True, False} &;

groupByIndex2 = Function[{d, f}, Values@Reverse@ KeySort @ 
  GroupBy[MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]]} &, d], f[Last@#] & -> First]];
```

Examples:

```
groupByIndex1[testArray, OddQ]
```

> {{"String A", "String C", "String E"}, {"String B", "String D"}}

```
groupByIndex1[testArray, EvenQ]
```

> {{"String B", "String D"}, {"String A", "String C", "String E"}}

```
groupByIndex1[testArray, PrimeQ]
```

> {{"String B", "String C", "String E"}, {"String A", "String D"}}

```
groupByIndex1[testArray, 2 < # <= 4 &]
```

> {{"String C", "String D"}, {"String A", "String B", "String E"}}

```
And @@ (groupByIndex1[testArray, #] == 
        groupByIndex2[testArray, #] & /@ {OddQ, EvenQ, PrimeQ, 2 < # <= 4 &})
```

> True